# How to delete a certain hashmap object against a key when using Jedis?

Tags: redis, jedis

Consider the following code;

```
      Map<String,String> playerData = new HashMap<>();
    playerData.put("1", "player");
    playerData.put("2","spectator");
    playerData.put("3","spectator");
    RedisHelper.getInstance().initialize();
    Jedis jedis = RedisHelper.getInstance().getJedisInstance();
    jedis.hmset("room1", playerData);
    Map<String,String> playerData2 = new HashMap<>();
    playerData2.put("4", "player");
    playerData2.put("5","spectator");
    playerData2.put("6","spectator");
    jedis.hmset("room1", playerData2);
```

I can delete the key completely using del method but I am unable to find a jedis method to delete hashmap object which is desired in this case as part of business requirement of the application. Methods srem or del can not work in this case. So far, I could not get help from google.
Any help will be appreciated in this regard.

Comment: DEL will delete the whole object. HDEL will delete a bunch of keys in an existing object. See http://redis.io/commands/del and http://redis.io/commands/hdel

Comment: Yes, I myself had found the solution given below; jedis.hdel(key,hashmapkey)....Thanks though.